# How to make form fill progress vertical scroll bar with jquery

Tags: jquery

its not simple progress bar. I was already get the simple progress bar but its not working. I Have need of a form fill progress scroll bar which can be scrolled up or down..

Comment: I would suggest you to complete what exactly you want, what you have tried and post your code. And probably use css and html tags depending how far you got with it.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Show us what you tried that isn't working and people try to help you fix it. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your application is very vague as to what you are looking to do with said progress bar, but here is a simple animated progress bar using JavaScript:

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.meter { 
 height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
 position: relative;
 background: #555;
 -moz-border-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.meter > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
  );
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h4>Simple animated progress bar</h4>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 


<h4>A static bar using CSS</h4>
<p>Just change the style statically or animate with Jquery/JS</p>
<div class="meter">
   <span style="width: 50%"></span>
</div>
```

[jQuery Progressbar Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

May help you out, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code and update value on every input fill.

```css
progress{
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);    
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressbar" value="60" max="100"></progress>
```